# Why is the multiplication of two sets their intersection, and the addition their union?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

Why is the multiplication of two sets their intersection, and the addition their union? e.g.

$$\{a,b,c\} + \{c,d,e\} = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$$

$$\{a,b,c\} * \{c,d,e\} = \{c\}$$

I don't know if this is true, but in an exercise, it was defined this way.

Comment: It is not - this is some particular (and, in my opinion, a little peculiar) alternative way of talking about union/intersection under different names. Presumably it makes more sense in context, depending on where you saw this exercise.

Comment: One often uses `+`and `*` for union and intersection if the symbols $\cup$ and $\cap$ are not available in your character set, e.g. older papers written with a typewriter or text documents written in ASCII

Comment: This comes, I think, from the algebra of logic tradition ( Boole in particular). You may have a look and Couturat's contribution here : https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.96323/page/n13/mode/1up

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if this is true, but in an exercise, it was defined this way.

If it's defined that way, then it's true, of course.

The notation is not widespread used, though.  What makes the notation a poor choice is that

1. There is already a short and established way to write intersections and unions, namely $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$ for uniion and intersection, respectively.
2. The notation is usually interpreted in a different way similar to when you apply a function to all elements of a set one writes $$f(A) := \{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$$ and similarly for a binary operation $\circ$ that operates on elments of $A$ and $B$: $$A\circ B := \{a\circ b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$$

Using convention 2, the semantics of the expressions would be:

$$\{a,b,c\} \circ \{c,d,e\} = \{a\circ c, a\circ d, a\circ e, b\circ c,b\circ d,b\circ e,c\circ c,c\circ d,c\circ e\}$$

where $\circ$ is one of $+$ or $*$.

One reason for using $*\equiv\cap$ and $+\equiv\cup$ migh be for typographic reasons when there is no terminal or keypord that can represent or input symbols `∩` and `∪`.